# Separating two hard drives (physically? SATA-Switch, Pulling Cords, ..)

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I need a recommendation regarding the (maybe physical) separation of a production environment (first OS on a sata hard drive) from another (second OS on a sata-hdd) - a bonus would be, If the first environment (production) would be unable to gain web-access (actually a completely different question).

What comes to mind first, is getting another machine to separate the drives: that is not possible.

What I need is a reliable method to seperate the two hard drives, so theire OSes can never know of the other HDD.

I heard of SATA-Power switches catching fire, destroying harddrives etc. Needless to say, that's not what I'm aiming for..

My first method of choice was using an "alternate frame" (to quickly swap hard drives from a 5,25" slot. But I was told SATA-Drives can only be re- and disconnected like 50 times. Is that right? Sounds like it's not.

Another method I was thinking of, is just opening the case each time, pulling/reconnecting plugs and pulling/reconnecting the ethernet cable.
Also, needles to say, that's not quite comfortable.

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you mean by "separate two hard drives"??? We need more details on your current setup and what the end result would be. And as far as the SATA drive SWAP limit of 50, that is completely false... If you are using the proper hardware, handling techniques, and not slamming the drives in and out like the gear shift lever in a dragster, they should last for hundreds or even thousands of swaps.

Comment: @acejavelin please read the third paragraph again... I need a reliably method to seperate two hard drives (so they don't know of each other) in ONE machine

Comment: @Everybody. Why the downvotes here? Any comment on WHY would be appropriate, wouldn't it? Not understanding the question is no reason.

Comment: Because it doesn't make sense... Hard drives don't know about each other, even in the same machine, the operating systems knows both devices, they are not joined somehow. Are they currently in a RAID configuration or something? The down voted are because your question is not clear...

Comment: Wow.. okay! I assumed that everbody firm with computers would know that I meant separation on OS level. Well, my bad. One HDD (with the first OS) and the other HDD (with the second OS) should not gain access to the other HDD respectively. - No RAID......

Comment: gotcha... So two OS's , one on each drive, and you don't want OS A to see the drive of OS B, and vice versa? That makes perfect sense. And I assume just simple configuration is insufficient, not allowing it mount or forcing it to disable the other OS's drive?

Comment: Exactly!! (Thats what I meant with "physical" separation)

Comment: then the answer below is appropriate,  but I would get 2 trays, one for each drive,  and quality ones that don't use the drives connection directly in the swap bay... Insert the drive you want and boot

Comment: So the ones with seperate enclosures for each drive. How about the bullsh*t I read about SATA being only able to be re- and disconnected about 50 times? That just can't be true. But will the drives suffer from being swapped all the time? (PC would always be turned off, of course)

Comment: there are various tray designs, you would have to research it, specific product recommendations are off topic here. A quality 5-1/4" Bay swap kit should be available that encloses the drive in the swap tray and doesn't the drive's connector each time but passes it through to a connector of the tray which engages in the dock itself. I know we have some drives on the bench that have been connected/disconnected hundreds of times with no issues, so I think that's BS but I can't collaborate it factually... I've never heard of a 50 connection limit or stress threshold

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to collect and rephrase the informations above lightly and post an answer, so I can flag it as the answer? :)

Comment: I have 4 more hours on the road... When I get home I certainly will

Answer (score 3):

Get yourself a removable drive bay/tray. I've used a unit in the past (cannot find a link to it anymore) where you mount a HDD in a special tray, then that tray slides into an enclosure that fits in a standard 5.25 drive bay. No wear and tear on the drive connectors themselves since the drive is mounted in a separate tray and the tray has its own connectors.

Optionally, to @acejavelin's point, you can get a drive bay that allows you to simply swap a SATA drive in and out (without the extra tray) using the drive's connectors directly.

Try googling: *sata drive bay tray*

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant with "alternate frame", that's exactly that. A 5.25 bay with exchangable frames containing the drives. Just worried about the statements, that SATA drives won't last long being handled like that. (Stated above, fifth paragraph)

Comment: BTW. The point of "wearing off" - I read that SATA devices are not designed to be dis- and reconnected a hundred or even a thousand times (but apprx. 50 times, which sounds like a bad joke - I know)

Comment: By using the tray, you are not connecting/reconnecting the drive itself; You connect the drive to the sled, and the connection is made between the sled and the frame. No wear and tear on the drive itself. If your concern is the SATA connectors on the sled & tray getting worn out, you can move the drive to a new sled if that ever happens. BTW- I disagree that this topic should be closed- you are looking for a solution, not a specific product.